# Removing html contents from a web request using C#

Tags: c#

I have the following code in `C#` which gets the contents of a web page and stores them in a string variable.

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.arsenal.com");
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
Stream data = response.GetResponseStream();
string html = String.Empty;
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(data))
{
    html = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

The code works properly but m I need to store the content of the page without the `html` tags and `Javascript` stuff. Is there any way to do so (any built-in method or something ready for such things)?
Actually I have found some ways for removing `html` tags but `Javascript` and `CSS` styles still bother me. I have to mention that the way for removing `html` is also not working well, I'm using regular expressions for doing so.

Comment: Find a library to do it. You will be entering a world of pain if you try writing something yourself. Probably a good time to post this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @GrandMasterFlush I was looking for a library too, but did not find anything

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c might be worth a look then. I've used HTMLAgility pack before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) suggests, it's a tricky process parsing HTML and the best approach is to use a library.

I've used the [HTML Agility Pack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack) before with some success though [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c) lists some other options.